# Why do all of my Select Options (Bootstrap HTML) show as selected in Chrome devtools, even though they are not?

Tags: android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, html-select

I'm attempting to determine if my JS code or Bootstrap is incorrect.
I seem to have a problem on the Android Chrome browser where the browser doesn't seem to know which Option select item is selected.

In Desktop chrome I noticed that the items look like the following:

[image: chrome dev tools]

Even though I only have one item selected they all seem to have the "selected" attribute set.

Is this just a Chrome Dev Tool problem? -- incorrectly displaying the items?
Does Bootstrap doe something odd with those items?
If I run the following jQuery on Desktop Chrome then it gives me the chosen (selected) item but seems to fail on Android Chrome:

```
$("#SiteListBox option:selected").text()
```

I'm trying to determine why there is any difference.

Comment: can we see code too? because its look like something adding selected attr to options

Comment: Thanks for your comment/question. I will look through and try to add the appropriate parts, but this is part of a somewhat large SPA.  Also, the code isn't super clean (blush).  This is my open source project that is hosted at github (https://github.com/raddevus/CYaPass-Web)  so you can look at the code there if you want --- but like I said large and contains some clumsy code.

Comment: Okay, you helped me find it.  
var localOption = new Option(decodeURI(atob(item.Key)), decodeURI(atob(item.Key)), true, true);
I'm setting true on each item of the Options that I add and the true sets it to selected.

Comment: good to know that you have found the issue. is it solve now already or should I work on it?

Comment: @Sodhisaab It is solved. If you'd like to add the answer I am glad to upvote and set as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like something adding `selected` attr to all options

check the following line in your code.

```
 var localOption = new Option(decodeURI(atob(item.Key)), decodeURI(atob(item.Key)), true, true);
```

Good Luck